# RabbitMQ/pika - Single RPC callback for multiple clients

Tags: python, rabbitmq, rpc, pika

I have followed the examples at the official [RabbitMQ site](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) and I then tried to take it a step further. I tried to apply the same RPC logic with a single server and multiple clients. Following the examples, I am using `BlockingConnection()` for now. Each client calls the `process_data_events()` function in a loop and check for it's corresponding `correlation_id`. **All of the clients check for their correlation id on the same callback_queue**.

For example, in a setup of 2 clients and 1 sever, there are 2 queues. One that both clients publish to, and one that both clients check for the corresponding `correlation_id`. The code works flawlessly with a single client and a single server (or even multiple servers), but fails to work when more than one clients consume on the callback_queue.

My experiments have showed that when a client receives (via the `process_data_events()`) an id that is not theirs, that id is **not processed** by the other client, ever. Hence a timeout occurs or the connection is dropped since no heartbeat is sent for quite some time. The function after which the problem occurs is `channel.basic_consume(queue='callback',on_message_callback=on_resp)`

Should I use a unique callback queue for each client? The documentation was not as helpful as I would have hoped, is there something you would recommend me studying?

I can post minimal code to reproduce the issue if you ask me to.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** This [repo](https://github.com/npaschos/PikaBlockingRPC) contains minimal code to reproduce the issue plus some more details.

Comment: Provide a complete, working code sample in a GitHub repository. That's the easiest way for me to assist.

Comment: Updated the question with a github repo url.

Comment: "My experiments have showed that when a client receives (via the process_data_events()) an id that is not theirs, that id is not processed by the other client" - correct, because the message has been consumed. The RPC tutorial code is meant to be the most basic introduction and not for production use. You should investigate the direct reply-to feature of RabbitMQ, and / or use a queue per-client for RPC responses. Finally, using BlockingConnection as the connection class probably isn't the best choice.

Comment: If you'd like to add me as a collaborator for your GitHub repository (I just starred it), I can give assistance as time allows. I maintain Pika and having a robust RPC example would be useful. I would prefer building it out with someone else, too. Thanks.

Comment: I added you as a collaborator. I would be happy to work with you.

Comment: I saw that, thanks. Please give my suggestions from an earlier comment a try. You can open pull requests against your own repository and I should see them to give input. Thanks.